# type observable<{}> is not assignable to any type:Property length is missing in type{} in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to get JSON data kept in the local system using Angular2 http.

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { General }        from './general';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GeneralService {
    // #docregion endpoint
    private statusUrl = './jsondata';  // URL to web API
    // #enddocregion endpoint

    // #docregion ctor
    constructor (private http: Http) {}
    // #enddocregion ctor

    // #docregion methods, error-handling, http-get
    getStatus (): Observable<General[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.statusUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
 private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }


    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

}
```

I'm getting error- **Type observable<{}> is not assignable to type 'Observable'.Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'General[]'. Property length is missing in type'{}'**

Here General is a class name. Im using rxjs-5.0. I'm following Angular.io Tour of heroes and making my own project. Any help on this?

Answer (score 6):

I changed my imports from
**import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';**
to
**import { Observable }     from 'rxjs';**
And it all worked

Comment: nice catch. had the same problem, solved thanks to you.  but why does it happens. what is wrong with 'rxjs/Observable' ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are telling to observable to get a list of Genral while you are getting an object.

```
getStatus (): Observable<General[]>
```

If you are not accepting an array then you should do like this

```
getStatus (): Observable<General>
```

Comment: @Protagonist you have body.data, are you sure you are getting data object beacuse data obejct use to be if you are reading a json file. try this
return body || { };

Answer (score 1):

I would adjust the `extractData` like this:

```
private extractData(res: Response): General[] {
    let body = res.json();
    return (body.data || []) as General[];
}
```

Now it says that it will return `General[]` and also it asserts the `body.data` to be of that type. In case, of null result, empty array is returned

Comment: Isn't res.json() of type `any`? If it is, then your typing would be redundant since both `any` and an empty array is compatible with any array.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler say that you try to assign an object to an array (of Generals).

I guess that your problem is in `return body.data || {}` in `extractData`. Try `return body.data || []` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The bad assign is not coming from the `extractData()` call but from the `catch()` one.

Try this:

```
getStatus(): Observable<General[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.statusUrl)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch<General[]>(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below:

```
getStatus(): Observable<Genral[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.statusUrl)
    .map((res) => this.extractData(res))
    .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
}
```